# Teradata Aggregation computation locally vs globally

Tags: teradata

I have two tables Table1 and Table2 with both tables having primary index as col1,col2,col3 and col4.
I join these two tables and do a group by on a set of columns which includes the PI of the tables.
Can someone tell me why in the explain plan I get "Aggregate Intermediate Results are computed globally"
rather than locally. My understanding is that the when the group by column contain all the PI column 
aggregate results are computed locally rather than globally.

```
select
A.col1
,A.col2
,A.col3
,A.col4
,col5
,col6
,col7
,col8
,col9
,SUM(col10)
,COUNT(col11)
table1 A
left outer join
table2 B
on A.col1 = B.col1
A.col2 = B.col2
A.col3 = B.col3
A.col4 = B.col4
group by A.col1,A.col2,A.col3,A.col4,col5,col6,col7,col8,col9
```

Below is the Explain plan for the Query

```
        1) First, we lock a distinct DATEBASE_NAME."pseudo table" for read on a
        RowHash to prevent global deadlock for DATEBASE_NAME.S. 
        2) Next, we lock a distinct DATEBASE_NAME."pseudo table" for write on a
        RowHash to prevent global deadlock for
        DATEBASE_NAME.TARGET_TABLE. 
        3) We lock a distinct DATEBASE_NAME."pseudo table" for read on a RowHash
        to prevent global deadlock for DATEBASE_NAME.E. 
        4) We lock DATEBASE_NAME.S for read, we lock
        DATEBASE_NAME.TARGET_TABLE for write, and we lock
        DATEBASE_NAME.E for read. 
        5) We do an all-AMPs JOIN step from DATEBASE_NAME.S by way of a RowHash
        match scan with no residual conditions, which is joined to
        DATEBASE_NAME.E by way of a RowHash match scan.  DATEBASE_NAME.S and
        DATEBASE_NAME.E are left outer joined using a merge join, with
        condition(s) used for non-matching on left table ("(NOT
        (DATEBASE_NAME.S.col1 IS NULL )) AND ((NOT
        (DATEBASE_NAME.S.col2 IS NULL )) AND ((NOT
        (DATEBASE_NAME.S.col3 IS NULL )) AND (NOT
        (DATEBASE_NAME.S.col4 IS NULL ))))"), with a join condition of (
        "(DATEBASE_NAME.S.col1 = DATEBASE_NAME.E.col1) AND
        ((DATEBASE_NAME.S.col2 = DATEBASE_NAME.E.col2) AND
        ((DATEBASE_NAME.S.col3 = DATEBASE_NAME.E.col3) AND
        (DATEBASE_NAME.S.col4 = DATEBASE_NAME.E.col4 )))").  The input
        table DATEBASE_NAME.S will not be cached in memory.  The result goes
        into Spool 3 (all_amps), which is built locally on the AMPs.  The
        result spool file will not be cached in memory.  The size of Spool
        3 is estimated with low confidence to be 675,301,664 rows (
        812,387,901,792 bytes).  The estimated time for this step is 3
        minutes and 37 seconds. 
        6) We do an all-AMPs SUM step to aggregate from Spool 3 (Last Use) by
        way of an all-rows scan , grouping by field1 (
        DATEBASE_NAME.S.col1 ,DATEBASE_NAME.S.col2
        ,DATEBASE_NAME.S.col3 ,DATEBASE_NAME.S.col4
        ,DATEBASE_NAME.E.col5
        ,DATEBASE_NAME.S.col6 ,DATEBASE_NAME.S.col7
        ,DATEBASE_NAME.S.col8 ,DATEBASE_NAME.S.col9).  Aggregate
        Intermediate Results are computed globally, then placed in Spool 4. 
        The aggregate spool file will not be cached in memory.  The size
        of Spool 4 is estimated with low confidence to be 506,476,248 rows
        (1,787,354,679,192 bytes).  The estimated time for this step is 1
        hour and 1 minute. 
        7) We do an all-AMPs MERGE into DATEBASE_NAME.TARGET_TABLE
        from Spool 4 (Last Use).  The size is estimated with low
        confidence to be 506,476,248 rows.  The estimated time for this
        step is 33 hours and 12 minutes. 
        8) We spoil the parser's dictionary cache for the table. 
        9) Finally, we send out an END TRANSACTION step to all AMPs involved
        in processing the request.
        -> No rows are returned to the user as the result of statement 1.
```

Answer (score 0):

you just use col1,col2,col3,col4 to aggregate
then it would be aggregate locall?

more details from this url:
http://www.teradataforum.com/teradata/20040526_133730.htm

Comment: but when my PI is subset of Group by columns all the data to be aggregated is already within the same AMP, isn't it?

Comment: i will take a try tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

I believe that is because of intermediate spool. You are using columns from that spool, not from original table for group by. I was able to compute the aggregate intermediate results locally using a volatile table.

Essentially what happened in this case is that I took the spool from step 5, gave it a name and enforced a PI on it. Since PI of volatile table is same as initial tables, the volatile table generation is also a local amp operation.

```
CREATE VOLATILE TABLE x AS
(
SELECT
A.col1
,A.col2
,A.col3
,A.col4
,col5
,col6
,col7
,col8
,col9
--,SUM(col10)
--,COUNT(col11)
from
table1 A
left outer join
table2 B
on A.col1 = B.col1
A.col2 = B.col2
A.col3 = B.col3
A.col4 = B.col4
--group by A.col1,A.col2,A.col3,A.col4,col5,col6,col7,col8,col9
)
WITH DATA PRIMARY INDEX (col1, col2, col3, col4)
;

SELECT
col1
,col2
,col3
,col4
,col5
,col6
,col7
,col8
,col9
SUM(col10)
COUNT(col11)
from
x
GROUP BY 
col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7,col8,col9
```